# Web Scraping with Python. Problems getting even rows of a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Above's code works well but it seems there is a problem finding all td elements since I get a data frame with only odd pages. I can't solve it, so I would appreciate any help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL to scrape
url = 'https://bases.athle.fr/asp.net/liste.aspx?frmbase=resultats&frmmode=1&frmespace=0&frmcompetition=268139&frmposition={page}'

# Create an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Loop through all pages (assuming there are less than range)
for page in range(4):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url.format(page=page))

    # Create a BeautifulSoup object with the content of the response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all the td elements with class datas0
    td_datas0 = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'datas0'})

    # Check if there are any results
    if len(td_datas0) == 0:
        break

    # Loop through each td element and extract the text
    for td in td_datas0:
        data.append(td.text.strip())

# Divide the data into columns
cols = ['Rank', 'Mark', 'Name', 'Club', 'Department', 'Frm_Ligue','Cat_Sex','Col8','Col9']

# Convert the data into a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+len(cols)] for i in range(0, len(data), len(cols))], columns=cols)

# Save the dataframe as a CSV file
df.to_csv('athle.csv', index=False)

print('Data saved to CSV!')
```

Answer (score -1):

**you should change the class name like datas0, datas1, datas2 like this line.**

td_datas0 = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'datas'+str(page)})

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL to scrape
url = 'https://bases.athle.fr/asp.net/liste.aspx?frmbase=resultats&frmmode=1&frmespace=0&frmcompetition=268139&frmposition={page}'

# Create an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Loop through all pages (assuming there are less than range)
for page in range(4):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url.format(page=page))

    # Create a BeautifulSoup object with the content of the response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all the td elements with class datas0
    td_datas0 = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'datas'+str(page)})

    # Check if there are any results
    if len(td_datas0) == 0:
        break

    # Loop through each td element and extract the text
    for td in td_datas0:
        data.append(td.text.strip())

# Divide the data into columns
cols = ['Rank', 'Mark', 'Name', 'Club', 'Department', 'Frm_Ligue','Cat_Sex','Col8','Col9']

# Convert the data into a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+len(cols)] for i in range(0, len(data), len(cols))], columns=cols)

# Save the dataframe as a CSV file
df.to_csv('athle.csv', index=False)

print('Data saved to CSV!')
```

Comment: Not sure I understood you well. You mean to replace only that line?

Comment: yes because every td element have different class like data0 next data1 like this.

Comment: I have tried your code but it only lists two pages where the first contains odd rows and the second even rows.